# Need suggestion to improve speed for word break (dynamic programming)

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, word-break

The problem is: Given a string s and a dictionary of words dict, determine if s can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

For example, given
s = "hithere",
dict = ["hi", "there"].

Return true because "hithere" can be segmented as "leet code".

My implementation is as below. This code is ok for normal cases. However, it suffers a lot for input like:

s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab", dict = {"aa", "aaaaaa", "aaaaaaaa"}.

I want to memorize the processed substrings, however, I cannot done it right. Any suggestion on how to improve? Thanks a lot!

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
        int len = s.size();
        if(len<1) return true;
        for(int i(0); i<len; i++) {
            string tmp = s.substr(0, i+1);
            if((wordDict.find(tmp)!=wordDict.end()) 
               && (wordBreak(s.substr(i+1), wordDict)) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: You are not using dynamic programming. You've implemented the naive brute force solution.

Comment: Note that regardless of the exact implementation, you can always trim the dictionary by eliminating compound words. Since `aaaaaa` is a compound word `aa-aa-aa`, and so is `aaaaaaaa`, you can reduce the dictionary to just `aa`. In a really smart approach, you can discover such compound words on the fly (i.e. when the compound word appears for the first time in the input string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are not using dynamic programming because you are not remembering the subproblems that you have already solved.

You can enable this remembering, for example, by storing the results based on the starting position of the string `s` within the original string, or even based on its length (because anyway the strings you are working with are suffixes of the original string, and therefore its length uniquely identifies it). Then, in the beginning of your `wordBreak` function, just check whether such length has already been processed and, if it has, do not rerun the computations, just return the stored value. Otherwise, run computations and store the result.

Note also that your approach with `unordered_set` will not allow you to obtain the fastest solution. The fastest solution that I can think of is O(N^2) by storing all the words in a trie (not in a map!) and following this trie as you walk along the given string. This achieves O(1) per loop iteration not counting the recursion call.

Comment: I don't think the string copies matter that much, once you memoize results. Remember that you need to create those strings anyway to use them as `std::map` keys.

Comment: You are right, I need to store the previous results somehow. However, as my approach tries to find a match then remove the matching part from the input string and continue testing on a smaller input. I can't store the processed parts by the ending position, yet storing the entire substring is costly...

Comment: @MSalters, the fastest solution will require also storing strings in trie, not in a `std::map`. In this case, you can run along the string, keep the current position in a trie and have `O(1)` for loop iteration and `O(N^2)` for the whole solution. The current approach will be `O(N^3)` the best, because on each iteration it will require `O(N)` copy and/or lookup. I'll update the comment to show this.

Comment: @Sarah, I've updated the answer, please check it. You can store the strings by the starting position, or even by their length.

Comment: @MSalters, in my previous comment I have mixed the words from `wordDict` and the strings for which the memorization is done. So a bit updated version: for memorization you do not in fact need `std::map` because string length will be enough as the dynamic programming key. And for the words, a trie will be a better structure because it will allow O(1) per loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

It's logically a two-step process. Find all dictionary words within the input, consider the found positions (begin/end pairs), and then see if those words cover the whole input.

So you'd get for your example

```
aa:       {0,2}, {1,3}, {2,4}, ... {20,22}
aaaaaa:   {0,6}, {1,7}, ... {16,22}
aaaaaaaa: {0,8}, {1,9} ... {14,22}
```

This is a graph, with nodes 0-23 and a bunch of edges. But node 23 `b` is entirely unreachable - no incoming edge. This is now a simple graph theory problem

Finding all places where dictionary words occur is pretty easy, if your dictionary is organized as a trie. But even an `std::map` is usable, thanks to its `equal_range` method. You have what appears to be an O(N*N) nested loop for begin and end positions, with O(log N) lookup of each word. But you can quickly determine if `s.substr(begin,end)` is a still a viable **prefix**, and what dictionary words remain with that prefix.

Also note that you can build the graph lazily. Staring at `begin=0` you find edges `{0,2}, {0,6} and {0,8}`. (And no others). You can now search nodes 2, 6 and 8. You even have a good algorithm - A* - that suggests you try node 8 first (reachable in just 1 edge). Thus, you'll find nodes `{8,10}`, `{8,14}` and `{8,16}` etc. As you see, you'll never need to build the part of the graph that contains `{1,3}` as it's simply unreachable.

Using graph theory, it's easy to see why your brute-force method breaks down. You arrive at node 8 (`aaaaaaaa.aaaaaaaaaaaaaab`) repeatedly, and each time search the subgraph from there on.

A further optimization is to run bidirectional A*. This would give you a very fast solution. At the second half of the first step, you look for edges leading to `23, b`. As none exist, you immediately know that node `{23}` is isolated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see that the approach of building graph lazily is more like a BFS in graph. Can I do DFS with dynamic programming? Which is better?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is formally "dynamic programming"; BFS and DFS are graph traversal algorithms. I'm not sure if you win with DFS, as you'd need to recursively do dictionary traversals.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) 
    {
        for (auto w : wordDict)
        {
            auto pos = s.find(w);
            if (pos != string::npos)
            {
                if (wordBreak(s.substr(0, pos), wordDict) && 
                    wordBreak(s.substr(pos + w.size()), wordDict))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Essentially one you find a match remove the matching part from the input string and so continue testing on a smaller input.

Comment: And is also wrong... the two section of the string have to be checked separately, otherwise one may find non-existing matches.For example given string aba with dictonary aa, b one could fins the maching b and then look for matching aa...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I changed my previous solution to the implementation below. At this point, I didn't explore to optimize on the dictionary, but those insights are very valuable and are very much appreciated.

For the current implementation, do you think it can be further improved? Thanks!

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool wordBreak(string s, unordered_set<string>& wordDict) {
        int len = s.size();
        if(len<1) return true;
        if(wordDict.size()==0) return false;

        vector<bool> dq (len+1,false);
        dq[0] = true;
        for(int i(0); i<len; i++) {// start point
            if(dq[i]) {
                for(int j(1); j<=len-i; j++) {// length of substring, 1:len
                    if(!dq[i+j]) {
                        auto pos = wordDict.find(s.substr(i, j));
                        dq[i+j] = dq[i+j] || (pos!=wordDict.end());
                    }
                }
            }
            if(dq[len]) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: "Can it be further improved" isn't a good question, it's too broad. Also, you posted this as an answer so there won't be many people who spot the question. (It's ok to post your final solution as an answer). That said, the setting of `dq[i+j]` is rather inefficient due to the implementation of `vector<bool>`. Just use an `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I appreciate it. I do notice vector<bool> is costly, but I don't quite know why. Can you elaborate more?